# Azure durable function "terminatePostUri" gives 404 when triggered

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm creating an Azure Durable function app where the orchestrator run for a while but I need an option to cancel the orchestrator if needed. I'm trying to use the "terminatePostUri" from Postman but it gives me a `404` response.

Other instance management uris like `statusQueryGetUri` are working as expected.

Here's a code snippet of my Terminate Function.

```
[FunctionName("klaviyo_terminate_instance")]
public static Task Run([DurableClient(TaskHub = "%KlaviyoTaskHub%")] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
    [QueueTrigger("terminate-queue")] string instanceId)
{
    return client.TerminateAsync(instanceId, "Called for terminate instance");
}
```

Here's the postman response.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

So apparently the terminate uri works as a POST request (but not GET) despite not having any payload. Not sure what the reason for that is.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api

Comment: It’s a best practice in REST API design that GET should be idempotent and not have side effects. Terminate does not meet this criteria, which is why it is instead POST.